Insufficient memory in resource pool 'internal'
I've had my SQL Server crash twice in the last week. The most recent was while executing a Database Integrity Check DBCC CHECKDB. The check failed and generated this error: There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query. I'm wondering if I have the memory settings correct. Running SQL Server 2019 with 128GB. Setting are:

If I understand this correctly I beleive this gives me around 9GB of space reserved for the OS. Do I need to tweak? Should Minimum memory per query be increased?
I ran sp_blitz and also saw this in the results, Some CPU cores are not accessible to SQL Server due to affinity masking or licensing problems. But I think that is a different issue that needs to be addressed and is not related to this problem.
Adding screenshots of results from procedures from Erik. Only including error log messages logged around the time of the incident.






The server is Standard Edition on Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU25-GDR) (KB5036335) - 15.0.4360.2 (X64)
Adding a couple more images that may be helpful. Tempdb info and some check db info.




probing
I can't give you an answer with the quite limited details you've provided, but I can give you some additional steps to figure out what happened and when. Given the message Some CPU cores are not accessible to SQL Server due to affinity masking or licensing problems, it's possible that some memory is inaccessible if it's attached to certain sockets, but we can come back to that. Most likely, some dimPerson set your Standard Edition VM up with 1 core per socket across > 4 sockets.
I would also expect to see messages in the sp_Blitz output noting issues like:

Memory pressure affecting queries
Memory offline due to CPU affinity, etc.

next steps
Using a few of my stored procedures, you can potentially figure out the problem. The link here will point you to what you need to install.
First, run sp_PressureDetector to see:

Relevant server-level wait stats
Memory consumers outside of the buffer pool
Exactly how many cores are inaccessible to SQL Server

EXEC sp_PressureDetector;
Second, run sp_LogHunter to find high priority messages in the error log over the last week. This should give you some insight into what was happening contextually when those errors were fired.
EXEC sp_LogHunter;

Finally, run sp_HealthParser to view some historical information about when you may have run into issues generally on the server over the last seven days:
EXEC sp_HealthParser 
    @warnings_only = 1, 
    @skip_locks = 1;

This may show you exactly when waits spiked and you hit any actual stack dumps. Of course, this is somewhat at the mercy of how much data is retained in the system_health Extended Event.
If you'd like help with any of the output, feel free to post screenshots as updates to your question, and I'll update this answer accordingly if there's anything further.
analysis
Looking at the error log output, during DBCC CHECKDB runs, you have something like 22GB allocated to MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIONS, and 102GB allocated to MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL.
SELECT
    MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIONS = 22320304 / 1000000,
    MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL     = 108768984 / 1000000

That is, somewhat obviously, all of the memory on your server. Even with max server memory set to ~115GB, you're still managing to bottom out memory. Also from the error log:

Last OOM Factor 3
Failed allocate pages: FAIL_PAGE_ALLOCATION 1

Memory grants for DBCC CHECKDB are pretty wild. If you were on Enterprise Edition, you could use Resource Governor to set up a workload group to run those commands with a much reduced percentage (by default, it's 25% of max server memory).
Since you're on Standard Edition, you could try splitting the DBCC checks into their constituent parts, like Paul Randal describes here:

CHECKDB From Every Angle

You may also want to try:

Removing the DATA_PURITY addition to your regular DBCC checks
Continuing to run them successfully with the TABLOCK option
Restoring full backups to another server to run DBCC CHECKDB on
Running DBCC CHECKDB with the PHYSICAL_ONLY option

As a test, you could also try reducing max server memory to a lower number (for instance, reduce it by ~8GB) to see if that prevents the OOM from occurring. I don't know if you have anything else running on the SQL Server, like SS(A/I/R)S, which may also be trying to contend for memory with SQL Server concurrent with the DBCC CHECKDB runs. If so, you may also need to account for outside memory needs. I'm also not sure if you have any A/V or other security scanning software installed, but if you do, make sure it's setup with the correct exclusions. While some of this is potentially unlikely as a culprit, I'm including it to cover some extra bases Just In Case™️.

I tested with the DATA_PURITY removed and added TABLOCK option and it crashed with the memory error again. New scanning software was installed. I will look into that.

Our systems engineer noticed that the last time we got this error was while performing CHECKDB on a database. Ran some tests and ended up rebuilding that database. Have not experienced the issue since rebuilding.
